# Is there a tool for winforms which can tell you what control your mouse is hovering on

Tags: .net, winforms

I seem to remember a tool that could be used at runtime to tell you what the type of a control was when you hovered your mouse over the control.

is there something similar for .Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Managed Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx) is great - displays properties in a property grid, includes full source code and provides a reusable library you can use in your application to monitor other WinForms applications.

Answer (score 2):

Here;s an article about ManagedSpy, which looks like it might be what you're after.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with any tools for this, so if someone else doesn't post a good, free one, a simple work around would be to do a foreach loop on me.controls and add a MouseEnter handler to each of them, then switch a class-level variable to the new Sender object in the event handler.

Then if you want the type of it displayed somewhere or something you can post it using .GetType().Tostring();